# SQL : Grouping Multiple columns optionally

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to use `group by` to the following table

```
id     ripped_file_name plate_length plate_width job_type_billing
665677 A                        23.5        26.0             1329
665678 A                        26.0        23.5             1329
665679 C                        26.0        23.5             1329
665680 D                        26.0        23.5             1329
665681 A                        26.0        23.5             1329
665682 A                        33.2        23.5             1329
```

`Group by` `ripped_file_name,plate_width,plate_length`

Where I want to add a case `where` `plate_width`,`plate_length` can interchange

Expected Result

```
id     ripped_file_name plate_length plate_width job_type_billing
665681 A                        23.5        26.0             1329
665679 C                        26.0        23.5             1329
665680 D                        26.0        23.5             1329
665682 A                        33.2        23.5             1329
```

So in this 1 st , 2nd and fifth row are grouped.

Comment: Please post text no image of text

Comment: i am not able to do as table thats y

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: What's your expect result from your sample data?

Comment: i have added expected result

Comment: even if length and width interchange i want them to be grouped as one if values are same. In actual result first  row wont be grouped

Comment: You couldn't live with a result where width was always shorter than length? It's a little easier that way.

Comment: i have added one more row under A , so the first 3 A's are grouped and the 3rd didnt as the value also was different. is it possible to group like that

Comment: To @Strawberry's point, something like `SELECT ripped_file_name, CASE WHEN plate_length < plate_width THEN plate_length ELSE plate_width END as measure1, CASE WEN plate_length < plate_width THEN plate_width ELSE plate_length END as measure2` and then GROUP BY those two. No worry about "Interchanging" and testing multiple scenarios and all that mess if you just stick the smaller measure first, and the larger second.

Comment: @JNevill You might as well submit that as an answer - although I'd go for LEAST and GREATEST in that instance.

Comment: It was your idea. You write it up ;) Especially with that much better `Least()` and `Greatest()`. I forget about that in mysql.

Comment: @JNevill While you will find hundreds of instances of hypocrisy on my part, I tend to resist answering questions that fail to provide proper DDLs.

Comment: Any suggestions @Strawberry

Comment: Only as per my original comment.

Comment: OK @strawberry. I took the torch. OP, you can find my interpretation of Strawberry's suggestion in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @strawberry's suggestion, you can stick the smaller measurement (length or width) in one column of your result set, and the larger in another column. Then group by those two derived columns:

```
SELECT 
    ripped_file_name, 
    LEAST(plate_length,plate_width) as measure1, 
    GREATEST(plate_length,plate_width) AS measure2
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY ripped_file_name, measure1, measure2
```

Comment: Of course, performance benefits aside, I couldn't stomach using GROUP BY in a non-aggregated query.... but perhaps there's something missing ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much. :)

Comment: This is why you should submit your own answers!

Comment: This is very simple logic, @Strawberry , i didn't understood earlier what u mentioned in the first comment, now I do, thank you both again